# How to keep the session when using nginx as the Reverse Proxy to many servers with unsame project

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx. And I have trobule with it. We have many projects with different language and framework. And they are put in different server. How do I keep the session for every project respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not quite clear but from what i understood i will try to guide you a bit...

Nginx is a web server which when used as reverse proxy basically just sits in front of your project appserver. When some client tries to connect to your appserver, it will first connect to nginx and then nginx will forward that request to you appserver.

eg.
client -Req-> nginx (port 8080) -Req-> appserver(jetty, port 9000)

Now if you are trying to use a single nginx instance and direct request to multiple app servers from nginx. You will either have to make nginx listen on different ports and forward them to different appservers. Or nginx can identify which request is meant for which appserver by routes.

Here is a source which can help you to learn how to configure Nginx to do this... please ask again if you need further help.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts